# How can i hide the content of a text field in android?

Tags: android, textview

I'm building a simple android program which contains a button(its id is submit)
and a textview (id is num).
I want the text to be changed each time submit button is clicked and i want the content of that text field to appear for 5 seconds and then disappears, I've written this program to change the text but i can't add a timer to hide the text!

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    int counter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final String [] arr=new String [4];
        arr[0]="345 765 6349" ;
        arr[1]="874 8743 23";
        arr[2]="7623 785 534";
        arr[3]="736 7634 343 ";
        counter=0;

        Button n = (Button)findViewById(R.id.next);
        final TextView display = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.num);
        n.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View V) {
                counter++;
                display.setText(arr[counter]);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You could use Handler as this:

```
n.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View V){
            counter++;
            display.setText(arr[counter]);
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        display.setText("");
                    }
                }, 5000);



        }
    });
```

Just check before "display.setText("");" that your activity is always resume.

Comment: @Tkmail, is it useful ?

Answer (score 0):

i'd recommend using a Handler.

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void run() {
                                          display.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                        }
                                    }, 5000L);
```